# Muliple IF AND statement excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to write a formula and getting error. The logic is:

```
If A1 > 0 and B1 = "PEN"   Output = "Refund 1"
If A1 > 0 and B1 = "INT"   Output = "Refund 1"
If A1 > 0 and B1 = "ADM"   Output = "Refund 1"
If A1 > 0 and B1 = "AB"    Output = "Refund 2"
If A1 < 0 and B1 = "PEN"   Output = "Fund 1"
If A1 < 0 and B1 = "INT"   Output = "Fund 1"
If A1 < 0 and B1 = "ADM"   Output = "Fund 1"
If A1 < 0 and B1 = "AB"    Output = "Fund 2"
```

I am getting errors writing multiples If-statements.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,OR(B1="PEN",B1="INT",B1="ADM")),"Refund 1",IF(AND(A1>0,B1="AB"),"Refund 2",IF(AND(A1<0,OR(B1="PEN",B1="INT",B1="ADM")),"Fund 1",IF(AND(A1<0,B1="AB"),"Fund 2"))))
```

Comment: Condensed version: `=IF(OR(B1={"PEN","INT","ADM"}),IF(A1>0,"Refund 1","Fund 1"),IF(B1="AB",IF(A1>0,"Refund 2","Fund 2"),""))`

Answer (score 0):

While @Jeanno's answer works for this case, I wanted to point out that you can accomplish the same thing more generally using a lookup table.

Items in blue are hard-coded, black are formulas.

[image: Image of Lookup Table]

There are a couple advantages to doing it this way:

- **Extensible**:  if your criteria suddenly grew from testing two conditions to 3 or more, the IF style statement is going to go from almost illegible to  completely illegible.
- **Clear**:  By looking up the value on a table, anyone can tell why a row is getting assigned to the result. Trying to do that with Excel's nested AND, OR, IF statements is really hard.